# Add a library from GitHub

Tags: android-studio, github

I want to use `SuperSaiyanScrollView` in my Android project (Android Studio)

https://github.com/nolanlawson/SuperSaiyanScrollView

When I add this line in my `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.nolanlawson:supersaiyan-scrollview:1.2.0@aar'
```

I get an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is launcher icon in the library clashes with the one in your project. **Rebuild the project after removing `android:icon` tag from your project's manifest file**. I tested the library in my project and got the same error. Here is Gradle Build Messages from my build.

> Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/lefo_icon) from
>   AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-43   is also present at
>   [com.nolanlawson:supersaiyan-scrollview:1.2.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:6:45-81 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
>     Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to 
>   element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-83:19 to override.
>   :app:processDebugManifest FAILED Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/lefo_icon) from AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-43    is
> >     also present at [com.nolanlawson:supersaiyan-scrollview:1.2.0]
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:6:45-81 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
> >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to 
> >     element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-83:19 to override.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.